# How to set Chrome's(headless mode) language in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to run Chrome headlessly with a particular language (e.g., French) in Cypress?

I have to run the suite in multiple languages.

I have added this code to plugin/index.js :

```
on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.name !== 'electron') {
        const language = config.env.lang || 'en';
        launchOptions.preferences.default.intl = { accept_languages: language }
        return launchOptions;;
    }
  });
```

It works if I run Chrome(headed) but headless it doesn't.